# Validation of numbers in a split string

Tags: java, validation, split

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.println("Enter your two numbers and the operation with spaces between e.g 8 9 -");

    String calculation=scan.nextLine();

    String [] parts = calculation.split(" ");

    double part1 = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
    double part2 = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);

    double answer = 0;
    boolean incorrectOperation = false;
    String operation = parts[2];
    switch (operation) {
        case "+":
            answer = part1 + part2;
            break;
        case "-":
            answer = part1 - part2;
            break;
        case "*":
            answer = part1 * part2;
            break;
        case "/":
            answer = part1 / part2;
            break;
        default:
            incorrectOperation = true;
    }

    String ans;
    if(incorrectOperation) {
        ans = "Please use +, -, * or / for operation";
    } else {
        ans = String.valueOf(answer);
    }

    System.out.println(ans);
  }
}
```

I had help regarding this calculator using a split string, i was wondering if someone could assist, or let me know how to validate the post fix expression that has been split up, the operation has already been validated using a Boolean but i need to know if i can validate the integers?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) you can catch the NumberFormatException.
In that case you can set your boolean and your error message.

For example :

```
double part1;
try {
  part1 = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
  System.err.println("The first argument was not a number.");
  System.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Integer.parseInt(myString ) and wrap it in a try/catch so if myString is not valid then you catch the exception.

Comment: we haven't really been through catching in my lab sessions how would it work?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to parse int numbers is

```
public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException
```

Comment: can you put this into my code but where would it go?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Scanner` method [`hasNextDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble()) to check to see if the next token can be read as a `double`, and then use [`nextDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) to retrieve it.